# Image superimposed on android emulator

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have not been able to find out why I use a  ASSUS ROG 2080 gpu super and this image is appearing on top of my android emulator. This is just with a standard File - > Xamarin Project.

Is it something to do with my 2080 super rather than my android emulator?

[image]

**Edit 2**
As you see its no where to be seen nore is it in the programs list.

[image]

Comment: what is a "2080 super"?

Comment: @Jason my GPU my graphics card this image seems to be being applied on top of all images in the emulator

Comment: @rogue39nin Try to open your `NVIDIA control panel` and disable the android emulator to use the graphics in the programe settings.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT but is that not why I have a fast emulator wont it hinder it ?.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT i dont see any settings for the emulator in my nvida controal panel can you be more specific.

Comment: @rogue39ninro When you use ASSUS ROG 2080 gpu super, open the NVIDIA control panelthe> Manage 3D settings>find the android emupator and delete it.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT its not their

Comment: @rogue39nin Check your golable seetings> Set the Preferred graphics processor to intet> Restart the android emulator to test. If it works, do the next steps. Change the Preferred graphics processor of golable seetings to NVIDIA. Then in Program Settings, find the emulator to do the change.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT its not an intel processer its amd

Comment: @rogue39nin 1. Could you provide the Golable Settings of NVIDIA control panel? Do not pull down the Preferred graphics processor, we want to check something. 2. What is the version of AMD cpu? 3. Which one you used to emulator, ARM image or  x86 image?

Comment: Its fine I found @WendyZang-MSFT it was actually not in the nvida control panel but asus on osd controll panel. Its where you can show the FPS say for a game it shows that logo if its activated within an application. Once I turned it off it went away.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT added the answer below strange one as have never seen that before in my day.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not inside the Nivda driver it self but it was actually in a program called CPU Tweek

If you see here the button at the top with on or off if you switch that off it will no longer appear

[image]

However if you want to see the Fps in an app on simulator leave it on and go to settings cog at the top of the screen. Then to the OSD tab and scroll down to photo and simply turn that off.

[image]